# Java ScheduledExecutorService - Need advice on real time performance issue

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, real-time, task

I have a created a multithreaded application that executes different tasks with the same ScheduledExecutorService (method scheduleAtFixedRate and a fixed threadpool of 10 threads). However all threads except one main task (not to be confused with the main thread!) are asleep most of the time, until there is user input. The data that is shared between the main task and the other (user input) threads is protected by lock objects in synchronized blocks.

The main task executes a reoccuring task at a fairly large frequency, let's say 25 Hz (i.e. period of 40 ms), and it's important that this task is executed timely. Typically this is also the case, but unfortunately not all the time. Other "nice" applications are also running on the same computer (Linux OP), but CPU<<100%.

During 60 minutes of measurement (i.e. 90000 samples) the actual period between two consecutive samples were >= 60 ms in about 50 cases, and in about 30 of these the period was over 100 ms, in a couple of really bad cases (fairly close to each other in time, in the order of seconds), the period was between 1000 and 2300 ms. No user input was given during measurement. Looking at the data logs, it seems obvious that something has prevented the executor from doing its job during these intervals, since they are often followed by a "catch up" of the Executor, i.e. multiple logs from the application within 2 or 3 ms.

I've tried periodic garbage collection at each execution of the task, but (at least in the short term perspective) it only seems to make things worse. I have also measured the execution time of the task. It is mostly around 1 ms, and it should not cause the Executor to break down (or should it?). There *are* deviations here too, occasionally in the order of 100 ms, but they would explain less than 50% of the delays. I have tried looking for TaskRejectedExceptions, found nothing.

So my questions now are basically: What can I expect from a ScheduledExecutorService over time? Is this likely to be a thread problem, despite the fact that only the main task should be running during these circumstances? What might cause the ScheduledExecutor to stop executing temporarily, only to flood the logs with its "catch up" data, and is there any method to control this annoying behaviour? Could any of this be related to the fact that my JVM is just a normal JVM without real time priority capabilities? Any help, ideas or theories on where to start digging, are truly appreciated!

Comment: I trust you are not judging the execution times of your tasks by the logged time of the task, but that you are explicitly measuring and printing out the time between invocations?

Comment: It's a bit confusing. So what you are saying you measured is the time between two executions of the main task's action that is supposed to execute every 40ms?

Comment: Very difficult to say, but logging and garbage collection can massively affect 'timely' performance. To focus on logging, you probably shouldn't have any logging code run in one of the executor's threads. Controlling GC occurences is out of my league and highly dependent on which JVM you are using. Best general tip is minimise object creations, but there *will* come a point when a GC interrupts your app (unless you tailor your app and JVM settings exactly).

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion! What I did was picking up a time stamp inside the code (using System.currentTimeMillis()) and writing it (using FileWriter) to a file. For each execution this procedure was carried out twice, once at the beginning of the run method and once very close to the end. Then I used the log file to calculate 1) the time delta between the time stamps written to file for each execution and 2) the period between two invocations of the run() method.

Comment: Paul, but if the logging itself was a performance problem the same order of magnitude as those glitches, wouldn't it occur all the time, not just in 50 out of 90000 cases? I tried to force garbage collection for each execution, just to avoid those 200 ms execution periods, but they persisted and instead the logs with execution periods ranging between 60-100 ms increased dramatically, with maybe 200%. :(

Comment: Oops, forgot to clarify - yes, the execution rate, i.e. time between invocations of run() method, used by the ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate was set to 40 ms.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Timer [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), your situation seems to be perfectly normal:

> In fixed-rate execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the scheduled execution time of the initial execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to "catch up." In the long run, the frequency of execution will be exactly the reciprocal of the specified period (assuming the system clock underlying Object.wait(long) is accurate).

The fact is that scheduleAtFixedRate() cannot guarantee that the execution will start exactly when it's supposed to start, but only the frequency in the long run.
Actually, I'm not sure if there's a way to accomplish that using Java.

Comment: There really isn't a way to accomplish that on most commondity operating system, you need a realtime OS. Even when running a C program under a realtime scheduler in linux, we found that it can't guarantee a fixed rate (though the ittering we measure are far less and not nearly as big as what the OP measuers in java)

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

- Calling the garbage collector does not guarantee collection quite the way you might think. From the Java doc:

> Calling this method suggests that the Java virtual machine expend
>   effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory
>   they currently occupy available for quick reuse.

The key here is suggests. Never expect it to operate exactly as you might expect. Nor can you expect it to stop the actual system garbage collection from running at another time.

- Threads are scheduled, but it is still up to the schedule to actually execute them. Your processor being at less than 100% usage does not mean that it is necessarily able to execute another thread. In general, expecting highly accurate realtime execution of threads within an environment you did not write completely from scratch is probably not going to lead to desired results.